# Chunking of matrix data into even sizes, what to do about remainders

Tags: python

My code below is how I currently divide the tile squares in my 2D game into chunks for performance optimization. However it's only possible if I use a matrix width and height which are both evenly divisible by the chunk size.

I would like the program to be able to make a smaller chunk size at the end of the width or height if needed, to be able to create any type of map sizes with any type of chunk size.

The tiles are already created in an earlier function and placed as a matrix (list of lists) in `self.tiles_list` to mimik the actual data matrix `self.data`.

```py
    def create_chunks(self):


        #-----Create chunks lists-----
        amount_chunks = (self.w * self.h) / (self.chunk_length * self.chunk_length)
        amount_chunks = int(amount_chunks)

        amount_chunks_width = self.w / self.chunk_length
        amount_chunks_width = int(amount_chunks_width)

        for i in range(amount_chunks):

            chunk = Chunk(i, self.chunk_length, self.chunk_length)
            self.chunks_list.append(chunk)


        #-----Insert tiles into chunks-----
        count_tile_list = 0
        count_chunk_list = 0
        count_chunk_list_adder = 0
        count_y = 0
        chunk_length = self.chunk_length


        for y, i in enumerate(self.data):

            if count_y == self.chunk_length:
                count_chunk_list_adder += amount_chunks_width
                count_y = 0

            for x in range(amount_chunks_w):
                
                for z in range(chunk_length):

                    chunk = self.chunks_list[count_chunk_list + count_chunk_list_adder]
                    chunk.tiles_list_temp.append(self.tiles_list[y][count_tile_list])

                    tile = self.tiles_list[y][count_tile_list]
                    tile.chunk = count_chunk_list + count_chunk_list_adder

                    count_tile_list += 1
                count_chunk_list += 1
            

            count_y += 1
            count_chunk_list = 0
            count_tile_list = 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have a better time if you just happily slice along your map without thinking about allocating the chunks beforehand.

Since you're sparse on the actual details of your map layout and so on, I can't give you a specific example, but the gist of it is explained here. <del>I'm using a Numpy matrix for the map here, since it's easy to slice into... well, chunks.</del>

This now supports both Numpy matrices and 2-dimensional list-of-lists.

```
from collections import namedtuple
import numpy as np

Chunk = namedtuple('Chunk', 'y x tiles')


def slice_chunk(map, x: int, y: int, chunk_w: int, chunk_h: int):
    """
    Get a chunk of (up to) (chunk_w x chunk_h) tiles from the map at (x, y).
    :rtype: if map is a list-of-lists, a list-of-lists; if map is a numpy array, a numpy array
    """
    if isinstance(map, list):
        return [row[x:x + chunk_w] for row in map[y:y + chunk_h]]
    elif isinstance(map, np.ndarray):
        return map[y:y + chunk_h, x:x + chunk_w]
    raise NotImplementedError("Don't know how to slice this")


def get_size(arr):
    """
    Get the size of a list-of-lists or a numpy array.
    :return: (width, height)
    """
    if isinstance(arr, list):
        return len(arr), len(arr[0])
    elif isinstance(arr, np.ndarray):
        return arr.shape[:2]
    raise NotImplementedError("Don't know how to measure this")


def get_chunks(map, chunk_w: int, chunk_h: int):
    """
    Yield chunks of (up to) (chunk_w x chunk_h) tiles from the map.
    :param map:
    :param chunk_w:
    :param chunk_h:
    :return:
    """
    w, h = get_size(map)
    for y in range(0, h, chunk_h):
        for x in range(0, w, chunk_w):
            chunk_tiles = slice_chunk(map, x, y, chunk_w, chunk_h)
            yield Chunk(y, x, chunk_tiles)


def main():
    tile_list = np.random.randint(0, 2, (100, 100)).tolist()
    for i, chunk in enumerate(get_chunks(tile_list, chunk_w=8, chunk_h=8)):
        print(f'Chunk {i} at {chunk.y}, {chunk.x} has {get_size(chunk.tiles)} tiles')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This prints out e.g.

```
Chunk 0 at 0, 0 has (8, 8) tiles
Chunk 1 at 0, 8 has (8, 8) tiles
Chunk 2 at 0, 16 has (8, 8) tiles
...
Chunk 12 at 0, 96 has (8, 4) tiles
Chunk 13 at 8, 0 has (8, 8) tiles
...
...
Chunk 155 at 88, 96 has (8, 4) tiles
Chunk 156 at 96, 0 has (4, 8) tiles
Chunk 157 at 96, 8 has (4, 8) tiles
...
Chunk 168 at 96, 96 has (4, 4) tiles
```

so as you can see, out of a map of size 100x100, with chunk size 8x8, you get 168 chunks, most of which are 8x8 as requested, but some are 8x4 and one is 4x4.

Comment: Thank you for the tip! However is there a way to modify my code to do the work? I've been trying a lot and would really want it to work since I'm very inexperienced with numpy

Comment: @Zoler1337 As I said, I don't know how you're storing your tiles. In a list of lists (`self.tiles_list[y][x]`)?

Comment: Yes exactly. They are objects which themselves have x/y coordinates and an image id (for drawing the right image tile).

Comment: Okiedoke. I edited in support for that format too, but if you don't need the Numpy stuff, you can just get rid of it. :)